# Spring Data java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

Spring is throwing

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.from(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/util/ClassTypeInformation;
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.MappingBuilder.isEntity(MappingBuilder.java:260)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.MappingBuilder.mapEntity(MappingBuilder.java:97)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.MappingBuilder.buildMapping(MappingBuilder.java:70)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.putMapping(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:156)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.putMapping(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:84)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.<init>(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:73)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.NumberKeyedRepository.<init>(NumberKeyedRepository.java:36)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:73)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:147)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:162)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:44)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1442)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:876)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:818)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
```

Here's my repository and this is the one causing the problem

```
@Repository("clinicalDocumentRepository")
public interface ConsultationDocumentRepo extends ElasticsearchCrudRepository<ConsultationDocument,Long> {
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: It's probably some dependency mismatch. Can you also show your dependencies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ClassTypeInformation introduced the method in version 1.1.0:

```
public static <S> TypeInformation<S> from(Class<S> type) {
```

Make sure your spring-data-commons version is >=1.1.0

Comment: is it different from Spring-Data-Commons 1.8.0 is it different from common core?

Comment: There seems to be a dependency mismatch on my maven. I have two spring-data-commons version. one is 1.8.0 and one is 1.6.0. but its supposed to be working

Comment: what is the version of spring-data-elasticsearch ?

Comment: Spring data es is on 1.0.0

Comment: I'd advise you to run mvn dependency:tree and have a look at it. I'll help you find out what's going on with your dependencies

Answer (score 1):

For the current Spring Data Elasticsearch release (1.0.0.RELEASE) you need Spring Data Commons in 1.8.0.RELEASE (as the [pom](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework.data%7Cspring-data-elasticsearch%7C1.0.0.RELEASE%7Cjar) suggests).

Generally speaking we recommend to use the release train BOM (as documented [here](https://spring.io/blog/2014/02/17/spring-data-release-train-babbage-sr3-released)) to make sure you get all Spring Data libraries in the matching versions. The current version for the BOM is `Dijkstra-RELEASE`.

Comment: So I'll add Spring Data Commons 1.8.0.RELEASE in my POM? I thought maven already does that automatically? I also have other versions of Spring Data, Spring Data JPA 1.2.0. Will it cause problems?

Comment: Spring Data JPA 1.2 is *not* compatible with Spring Data Elasticsearch 1.0. Spring Data ES is part of the Dijkstra release train, so here [are](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework.data%7Cspring-data-releasetrain%7CDijkstra-RELEASE%7Cpom) the compatible versions.