# Spring Data java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in grails

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, grails, spring-data-neo4j

I am using mongo db plugin and spring-data-neo4j in my grails application.

I am using latest version of SDN and mongo db plugin.

Here is my buildconfig :

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"
grails.server.port.http = 1111
grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0-grails-2.4"

        compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j-rest:3.2.0.RELEASE'

    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.7'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.6"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.5" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.17"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

        compile ":mongodb:3.0.2"

        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
    }
}
```

With this configuration i am getting following error :

```
Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTransactionManager' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDatastore' while setting bean property 'datastore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.from(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/util/TypeInformation;
    Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1146 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    701 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTransactionManager' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDatastore' while setting bean property 'datastore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.from(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/util/TypeInformation;
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1146 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    701 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDatastore' while setting bean property 'datastore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.from(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/util/TypeInformation;
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1146 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    701 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.from(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/util/TypeInformation;
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1146 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    701 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.from(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/util/TypeInformation;
->>  255 | createMongoTemplate in org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoDatastore
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    221 | afterPropertiesSet in     ''
|     54 | getObject in org.grails.datastore.gorm.mongo.bean.factory.MongoDatastoreFactoryBean
|    334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1146 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    701 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

I am using grails 2.4.3 and groovy 2.3.

Comment: Hmmm - if this is a new app, it should "just work". But if you look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380857/spring-data-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror) (and your stacktrace) it's clearly a newer jar calling a method in an older one and not finding a method or method overload that it can work with.